# php multidimensional array sort by date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which contains data that has date fields. Some indexes may have single date fields, others may have multiple. An example of an index with multiple date is listed below.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ()
... ... ... 
    [21] => Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
          [Date] => 2011-05-12
          [Color] => green
          [State] => Ohio
        )
       [1] => Array ( 
         [Date] => 1999-01-23
         [Color] => red
         [State] => Vermont
        )
       [2] => Array ( 
         [Date] => 3001-08-24
         [Color] => yellow
         [State] => Alaska
        )
```

I am trying to list them as the most current date to be the first entry down to the oldest entry. For example

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ()
... ... ... 
    [21] => Array (
       [0] => Array ( 
         [Date] => 3001-08-24
         [Color] => yellow
         [State] => Alaska
        )
        [1] => Array ( 
          [Date] => 2011-05-12
          [Color] => green
          [State] => Ohio
        )
        [2] => Array ( 
         [Date] => 1999-01-23
         [Color] => red
         [State] => Vermont
        )
```

I have tried

```
function date_compare($a, $b){
    $t1 = strtotime($a["Date"]);
    $t2 = strtotime($b["Date"]);
    return $t2 - $t1;
}
```

I get an error of

```
Notice: Undefined index: Date in date_compare() for both lines of $t1 and $t2
```

And when I put

```
function date_compare($a, $b){
    $t1 = strtotime($a[0]["Date"]);
    $t2 = strtotime($b[0]["Date"]);
    return $t2 - $t1;
}
```

I get an error of

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in date_compare(). On the second line $t2.
```

Note: The Array starts off with a [0] index, then it goes into [0], [1], [2].

Comment: Strtotime won't work on dates that far ahead (as of now). It's somewhere 2038 that is the max number with 32 bit UNIX time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First loop the array and sort the sub array using usort. For example considering the array to be

```
$array = array(array(
            array('Date' => '1999-01-23','Color' => 'red','State' => 'Vermont'),
            array('Date' => '3001-08-24','Color' => 'yellow','State' => 'Alaska'),
            array('Date' => '2011-05-12','Color' => 'green','State' => 'Ohio'),
            ),
            array(
            array('Date' => '2017-01-23','Color' => 'red','State' => 'Vermont'),
            array('Date' => '2017-08-24','Color' => 'yellow','State' => 'Alaska'),
            array('Date' => '2000-05-12','Color' => 'green','State' => 'Ohio'),
            )
       );
```

Sorting code:

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['Date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['Date']);
    return $t2 - $t1;  // descending
}  
  $sorted_array = array();
// loop the array
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    usort($value, 'date_compare'); // sort the array
    $sorted_array[$key] = $value;  // assign sorted array to new array
}

print_r($sorted_array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Date] => 3001-08-24
                    [Color] => yellow
                    [State] => Alaska
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Date] => 2011-05-12
                    [Color] => green
                    [State] => Ohio
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Date] => 1999-01-23
                    [Color] => red
                    [State] => Vermont
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Date] => 2017-08-24
                    [Color] => yellow
                    [State] => Alaska
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Date] => 2017-01-23
                    [Color] => red
                    [State] => Vermont
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Date] => 200-05-12
                    [Color] => green
                    [State] => Ohio
                )

        )

)
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/631c4b904d937ad181ccff20cbd3fa89c697f06b